# AngularJs 1.6 get values of form

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs and having some struggle.

Angular App:

```
// getting specs category
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/sjb/public/admin/angular/events/deelnemers/edit/specs',
    data: {'specid': 11}
}).then(function successCallback(response){
    $scope.SpecCategory = response.data;
    console.log($scope.SpecCategory);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("Fout met ophalen specs ID 11.");
});
```

Front-end

```
<select name="category" ng-model="user.cat_id">
    <option ng-repeat="Cat in SpecCategory" ng-selected="Cat.spec_value == editEventUser.cat_id" value="{{Cat.spec_value}}">{{ Cat.spec_name }}</option>
</select>
```

values

> Cat.spec_value = 1
>
> editEventUser.cat_id = 1

But the option is not "selected" ?

Please help; what is wrong that

```
ng-selected="Cat.spec_value == editEventUser.cat_id"
```

Doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be in the documentation for [ng-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected):

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel
>   directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you
>   are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the
>   options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

Given your current code if you want to use ng-model, you have to remove ng-selected and make it so that `user.cat_id` is used to match one value in you select.

```
<select name="category" ng-model="user.cat_id">
    <option ng-repeat="Cat in SpecCategory" value="{{Cat.spec_value}}">{{ Cat.spec_name }}</option>
</select>
```